# UDK/ UnrealScript class interaction? HUD advice?

Tags: gui, unreal, udk

Beginner basics requested here, While i'm familiar with the basics of OOP programming i've just started looking as UnrealScript for a game i had made in the UDK editor up to now.

I have a class that extends UTHUD and another that extends UDKPAWN. I have the pawn destroyed when its been shot 3 times and some basic helloworld text displaying in my HUD but i'm completely lost as to how one would get some sort of feedback between the two classes going on?

What i would like to do to start off, is have some text that says something like "Amount of baddies killed: 0" Displayed on the HUD which would then increment each time the player destroyed one of my pawns.

I'm sorry if this is an inappropriate question but i've never really worked within a framework like this before and wasn't sure where to go for help to get my footing. All advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i created my own class that extended UTPlayerReplicationInfo and had a variable baddiesKilled.

Then in my game type class i added this line to default properties:

```
PlayerReplicationInfoClass = class'myPlayerReplicationInfo'
```

Then in the HUD class:

```
function DrawGameHud()
{
local myPlayerReplicationInfo PRI;

PRI = myPlayerReplicationInfo(PawnOwner.PlayerReplicationInfo);

Canvas.SetPos(Canvas.ClipX/2,Canvas.ClipY/6);
Canvas.SetDrawColor(255,60,210,255);
Canvas.Font = class'Engine'.static.GetLargeFont();
Canvas.DrawText("Baddies Killed=" + PRI.baddiesKilled);

}
```

Hope someone finds this useful.